# Is it acceptable to hyphenate people’s names?

Tags: hyphenation

In some circumstances, for example, `B.~Alexander` may result in *B. Alexan-*`newline`*der*.  Is this acceptable?

If not, is there an elegant way to suppress it?  (`\hyphenation` is too cumbersome and sometimes inflexible.)

Comment: Why is the usage of `\hyphenation` too cumbersome? I would say it is easy to just add all the name(s) in `\hyphenation{Alexander}` in your preamble, no?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whether proper names may or should not be hyphenated is a matter of style.  I found several publishing houses that discourage it, among them [University of Houston](http://www.uh.edu/policies/editorialstyle/h/index.php).  UH says their style comes from the [Associated Press Stylebook](http://www.apstylebook.com/) (non-free).

Answer (score 18):

You can also type `\uchyph=0` to systematically prohibit the hyphenation of words beginning with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Not usable in German, I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use an `\mbox` to avoid hyphenation of the name:

```
\mbox{B.~Alexander}
```

Comment: Did you mean `B.~\mbox{Alexander}`?

Comment: The `~` inserts a non-breaking space between `B.` and `Alexander`. `Alexander` is already protected by the `mbox`, so the result of both variants should be the same. If you decide to define a command that typesets a person's name, you would probably put all the name's parts into one `mbox` anyway, as a start.

Comment: My apologies for this thoughtless question...

Comment: @Christoph, actually, there **is** a difference: in `\mbox{B.~Alexander}` the space is set at its 'natural' width: it can't stretch or shrink along with the other spaces on the line.

Comment: Thanks @Lev, I didn't take that into account. As spacing and hyphenating are related with regard to line justification, you are making an important point. Can we agree on `\mbox{Lev} \mbox{Bishop}` and `L.~\mbox{Bishop}`?

Comment: @Christoph: those seem good if you want to avoid hyphenating names. Personally, I usually just write `Lev Bishop` and `L.~Bishop` because if a tex chooses to hyphenate a name then it is usually the *least bad* of the possible ways to break a line, and forcing the issue with mboxes just makes an over/underfull line.

Comment: How do you deal with bad boxes resulting from the non-hyphenation of those words?

Comment: @levesque: When I see a bad box appearing around such a non-hyphenated name, it was my choice to get that bad box in the first place. If it is really disturbing to the eye, I try re-phrasing the surrounding text based on the assumption (or fact) that my wording was not optimal anyway. `microtype` helps.